# Getting vhost to redirect correctly for wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I'm trying to achieve 3 things on my server:

1. cat.mydomain.com should point to /home/www/
2. *.mydomain.com should point to /home/www/project/web/
3. *.mydomain.com/indexed/ should point to /home/www/indexed/

For this I've set up a httpd-vhosts.conf file with the following rules:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cat.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias cat.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.mydomain.com/indexed/
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com/indexed/
    DocumentRoot /home/www/indexed/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/project/web/
    ServerName *.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Two of these work like expected, cat.mydomain.com points to /home/www/ and *.mydomain.com points to /home/www/project/web/, but it's obviously not the correct way to redirect the directory *.mydomain.com/indexed/ as that does not work. How can I get that to work? Is the vhost section the right place to do this or should it be done in a .htaccess file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias), [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) cannot contain wildcard so this

```
ServerName *.mydomain.com
```

is just plain wrong. Also reading the documentation for ServerName shows the following syntax

> **Syntax**:   `ServerName [scheme://]fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]`

so

```
ServerName *.mydomain.com/indexed/
```

is wrong too. You should also review the syntax for ServerAlias because you have that wrong in some cases as well.

You should take a look at the [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive. Inside your vhost definition a suitable Alias should do just what you want.

Comment: Alias looks like it might be a good place to look. I'll also have a look at the other errors and see if I can get it correct:)